# Differences with browser displays

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I've made my website to completely support Google Chrome instead of Firefox or IE. Call me because now i've found that wasn't really smart: my website looks totally different on Firefox.

There aren't big differences, but a lot of items are misplaced with a few pixels. This doesn't sound that bad, but it is. For instance, this is how Chrome shows the page (look at the red button): http://d.pr/i/YNha and this: http://d.pr/i/8YZO is how Firefox shows the page. As you can see there are a few differences with the position of the image.

I really don't know what causes this, and i've already searched the web for similar problems without finding any solution.

This is the CSS that is used for the image:

```
.img (
margin-top: -130px;
margin-left: 520px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
HTML & CSS:

```
    <div style="background-image: url(http://linehotel.org/c_images/veiling_item.png);                    height: 401px; border-radius: 10px;">

    <div style="color: white; padding: 12px;">
    <center><img src="/c_images/veiling_teas.gif" /></center>

    <img src="/c_images/bod_teas.gif" /><br>
    <h1>
    <div style="z-index:1;width: 64px; height: 96px; float: left; margin-top: -25px; background: url(http://habbo.it/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=sh-295-85.hr-802-31.ch-3015-82.hd-180-2.lg-275-92&amp;gesture=sml&amp;size=b&amp;img_format=gif);"></div>
    Xice:                <br>0 credits</h1>
    <a href="/bied-mee"><img src="/c_images/closed.png" style="margin-top: -130px; margin-left: 520px;" /></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='/veiling'">
    <center><font size="1px"><i>De pagina update in real-time. Je hoeft zelf niet de pagina te herladen.</font></i></center>
```

Comment: Can't you share the full code -both Html & css? Or perhaps a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Ankit is right - more information would be helpful. As a shot in the dark: Did you use `display: table-cell`?

Comment: You don't "build it for a browser" you test in all browsers you need to support from the start, from the first few lines of markup so you can work around browser differences easily in the beginning... it will be a lot harder to do at the end of design. Post the complete markup or it won't be answerable. In Chrome (and Firebug) you have a really good element inspector where you can quickly play with the CSS properties and re-arrange DOM elements - use that to debug issues like this.

Comment: Updated with the HTML & CSS parts (css was put in the div style's)

Answer (score -1):

With the lack of information this isn't definitive but here's my answer.

Browsers use different default values for margins, paddings and other css styles. To help your site render the same in each browser you can try using reset css. Here is an example,

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS"
}
```

This will set the values for every element on the screen effectively ignoring any browser defaults. Then any class and inline style override these in turn.

For more extended reset styles have a look here, http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: If you don't have enough information to provide an answer, then it's better not to try.

Comment: @cimmanon, there was some information for some kind of answer. They have said their site renders differently and the answer give one possible solution. Once the OP has expanded on on their question I will expand on the answer.